# How to configure wordpress ajax load more plugin for api response data?

Tags: wordpress

> Ajax wordpress load more plugin configuration for api response data.

Comment: What exact you want to do?
Can you please explain in brief?

Comment: I called a third party software API and I want to send page no in API parameter. I used 'php code' plugin  in wordpress to display API response.I just want to add pagination and got page number in wordpress page and send those page number as a API page no parameter. I want to implement load more button like pagination in wordpress.